# WSGIPythonPath is not working

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi, pythonpath

I am deploying my web.py application on Apache2 with mod_wsgi.

Here is my virt_host file,

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/plotwatt/libplotwatt:/home/ubuntu/plotwatt/pwstage/src

<VirtualHost *:20108>
ServerAdmin gslabrails.dev.plotwatt.com

DocumentRoot /var/www
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/currentcost/server.py
WSGIDaemonProcess currentcost user=ubuntu group=ubuntu processes=5 threads=3
WSGIProcessGroup currentcost
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
AddType text/html .py

<Directory /var/www/currentcost/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/currentcost_error.log
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/currentcost_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have given path to my lib named redisStage in WSGIPythonPath. But, it seems to be not working for me. Am i making any wrong configuration?
I can't put WSGIPythonPath directive inside VitualHost directive.
What must be the reason ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath), you cannot use `WSGIPythonPath` when using daemon mode. Use the 'python-path' option to the [WSGIDaemonProcess directive](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess) instead.

Comment: same note goes for django and [modwsgi daemon mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#daemon-mode)