# Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Django 1.11.7
I installed the python3.6 in the virtual environment.
why is it Python/3.5.2 here?
and

## I cannot visit the web 127.0.0.1 (500 internal server error)

[wsgi:error] [pid 61905:tid 140688926893824] [remote 127.0.0.1:33456] mod_wsgi (pid=61905): Target WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/.../wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] [pid 61905:tid 140688926893824] [remote 127.0.0.1:33456] mod_wsgi (pid=61905): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/.../wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 61905:tid 140688926893824] [remote 127.0.0.1:33456] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error] [pid 61905:tid 140688926893824] [remote 127.0.0.1:33456]   File "/home/ubuntu/.../wsgi.py", line 32, in 
[wsgi:error] [pid 61905:tid 140688926893824] [remote 127.0.0.1:33456]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

## [wsgi:error] [pid 61905:tid 140688926893824] [remote 127.0.0.1:33456] ImportError: No module named 'django'

how to solve above problem?

Help! thks!!!

Comment: Can you cross check if you are working in correct virtualenv and it is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

As is documented, you cannot point mod_wsgi compiled for one Python version at a Python virtual environment created from a different Python version.

Your mod_wsgi has to be compiled for the Python version you want to use.

Comment: I encountered same error as above and my virtual env version is 3.6. I compiled mod_wsgi earlier with python 3.5. How can we point mod_wsgi to newer version?

Comment: It works finally after updating mod_wsgu version in apache configuration. For those who are getting this error can look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44915354/12113049