# Deploy django 2.0 with python3.6 on ubuntu 16.04 with mod_wsgi and apache2.4

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm trying deploy django with apache2.4 mod_wsgi on ubuntu,but i'm giving an error.

First install packages: `sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install virtualenv python-setuptools python3.6(from ppa) python3-pip python3.6-dev libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 apache2 mysql-server`

Ok, All install correctly.
So, I create a folder project `mkdir /mnt/g/development/matrix`
Create a virtualenv `virtualenv --python=python3.6 env` and activate
Install django2.0 from pip `pip install django` - ok install and check

```
 which python
```

/mnt/g/development/matrix/env/bin/python

```
python -V
```

Python 3.6.3

So I create a vhost on apache

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 127.0.0.50
        ServerAlias matrix.local

        DocumentRoot /mnt/g/development/matrix/framework

         Alias /static /mnt/g/development/matrix/framework/static
         Alias /media /mnt/g/development/matrix/framework/media

        <Directory /mnt/g/development/matrix/framework/framework>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
                </Files>
         </Directory>


        <Directory /mnt/g/development/matrix/framework/media/>
                Require all granted
         </Directory>

         <Directory /mnt/g/development/matrix/framework/static/>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess matrix processes=2 threads=5 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/mnt/g/development/matrix/framework/:/mnt/g/development/matrix/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup matrix
WSGIScriptAlias / /mnt/g/development/matrix/framework/framework/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

So, I start apache and mysql server, but I give an error

> (env) root@WILLIAM:/mnt/g/development/matrix# tail
>   /var/log/apache2/error.log [Tue Jun 19 04:01:10.947533 2018] [:error]
>   [pid 14811] [remote 127.0.0.1:28540] mod_wsgi (pid=14811): Target WSGI
>   script '/mnt/g/development/matrix/framework/framework/wsgi.py' cannot
>   be loaded as Python module. [Tue Jun 19 04:01:10.948034 2018] [:error]
>   [pid 14811] [remote 127.0.0.1:28540] mod_wsgi (pid=14811): Exception
>   occurred processing WSGI script
>   '/mnt/g/development/matrix/framework/framework/wsgi.py'. [Tue Jun 19
>   04:01:10.948034 2018] [:error] [pid 14811] [remote 127.0.0.1:28540]
>   Traceback (most recent call last): [Tue Jun 19 04:01:10.948034 2018]
>   [:error] [pid 14811] [remote 127.0.0.1:28540]   File
>   "/mnt/g/development/matrix/framework/framework/wsgi.py", line 12, in
>    [Tue Jun 19 04:01:10.948534 2018] [:error] [pid 14811]
>   [remote 127.0.0.1:28540]     from django.core.wsgi import
>   get_wsgi_application [Tue Jun 19 04:01:10.948534 2018] [:error] [pid
>   14811] [remote 127.0.0.1:28540]   File
>   "/mnt/g/development/matrix/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/**init**.py",
>   line 1, in  [Tue Jun 19 04:01:10.949034 2018] [:error] [pid
>   14811] [remote 127.0.0.1:28540]     from django.utils.version import
>   get_version [Tue Jun 19 04:01:10.949034 2018] [:error] [pid 14811]
>   [remote 127.0.0.1:28540]   File
>   "/mnt/g/development/matrix/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/version.py",
>   line 61, in  [Tue Jun 19 04:01:10.949534 2018] [:error] [pid
>   14811] [remote 127.0.0.1:28540]     @functools.lru_cache() [Tue Jun 19
>   04:01:10.949534 2018] [:error] [pid 14811] [remote 127.0.0.1:28540]
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

If I use the same code on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python3.4.5 default I'ts work.
Where I'm wronging?

My WSGIDeamonProcesses path it's right?

Thanks

Comment: Your `mod_wsgi` may have been compiled for Python 3.4. See this question for building your own `mod_wsgi`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44914961/install-mod-wsgi-on-ubuntu-with-python-3-6-apache-2-4-and-django-1-11

Comment: I try this and I've the same problem, I believe that my vhost config be wrong. But I not found any tutorial to correctly deploy setup for python3.6 and mod_wsgi

Comment: I would question whether mod_wsgi for correct version of Python is installed as well. Check using http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: Also review http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html for the correct way to configure mod_wsgi for a virtual environment.

Comment: thanks Graham! I solved uninstall libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 and install from pip mod_wsgi inside virtualenv and copy path from mod_wsgi --config and past module path to vhost.